# Best way to access images outside of a project?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image

I currently have several WPF projects that need to access a folder of images. What would the best way be to allow the projects to have access to the same images folder w/out duplication?

example structure:

- Root Folder

  - Images
  - Project 1
  - Project 2
  - Project 3

I'm familiar w/ adding the "needed" images to the actual project itself, but am looking for a solution for the projects to have the same "central" library of images.

Comment: Why not simply add them to the project from that location and select "Always copy [to output directory]"?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible with resources, but did you try adding the images to the project using the option - "Add as Link"?

Comment: @ Ed S. - I thought about this idea, but wouldn't that still create duplication? If project 1 and project 2 both want to use image1, then wouldn't there be two image1's if I was to add it individually into each project that needs it?

Comment: @ Orchestrator - I've tried this, and it works great. I am currently looking into other solutions but so far this has been the easiest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place all your images in a central project and reference them via the pack syntax throughout your solution.

```
ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/MyProject;component/Images/MyImage.png"
```

Comment: what type of "project" would be used? after project is released, would I be able to switch out an image from /Images/ (that has the same name as an existing one) w/out the need to do a fresh rebuild?

Comment: You can use any project type (class, WPF), I typically have an infrastructure project which houses infrastructure type components for the solution. You would not be able to switch out the images as it is pulling them from the compiled DLL.

Comment: sorry, one more question. is there a reason why the images only show up during designer mode and not when the app. is actually ran?

Comment: @ Aaron - Yeah, not too sure what's going on. They show up in the designer perfectly but I am unable to see them during run-time.

Comment: @iimpact Make sure to mark the images as a Resource, rebuild all, and check again. Also, make sure your _infrastructure_ DLL is being deployed to the root folder of your solution.

Comment: @iimpact Also need to add your reference to image project.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to reduce the size of your deployed assembly and to keep the image files 'loose', you might consider the 'site of origin' scheme.  It is the same format, but uses 'siteoforigin' for the authority rather than 'application'.

pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Subfolder/SiteOfOriginFile.jpg

Comment: the 'loose' files is what I am looking for. couldn't I include these files as "add-as-link" and then set the build to "content"?

Comment: That depends upon your deployment strategy.  Items marked as 'content' are loose, *BUT* the application knows about them at compile time and inserts metadata about them into the assembly.  Because of that, you can simply use the 'application' authority URI's like the others here have suggested.  If you wanted totally loose and no relation to your assembly, then 'site of origin' is the way to go.

Comment: thanks Garry. These images are typically going to be used as gui icons. Is there a way to swap out the images and change the image picture w/out rebuilding/compiling?

Comment: If the stuff being swapped have the same names, you're ok.  Otherwise to avoid a rebuild, you would store the URI's as string literals in the app.config.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the path to those images in your application.This will avoid the copy of images in your project. But if you package installer you need to package them properly.